# Excel automation - Reset fullname of a template workbook

Tags: excel, automation, activex

I'm generating automatic report with excel as back-end and I'm starting from a predifined template in which I'm only feeding missing parts:

```
excelApp = actxserver('Excel.Application');
excelWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open('Mytemplate.xslx');
excelWB.Saved = false;
... Feed template with effective data ...
```

What I would like is to be able to reset the fullname of the opened template workbook so that when the user clicks on the close button he will prompt for `Save`, `SaveAs` as usual but clicking `Save`should ask for a file location and not overwrite the exsiting template.

Is it possible ? (I tried resetting manually `Path` and `FullName` properties of the workbook object but these are read-only so it doesn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your "Mytemplate.xlsx" file as a Workbook Template instead (".xltx" file). When you open a template file it creates a new instance of the file each time instead of opening the original file. Additionally the default behavior of this new file is that the "Save" method will prompt for a file location.